# jQuery move all children to another div

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` with many childen. How do I move all of them to another `div` using `jQuery`?
my code looks like:

```
jQuery("body").append("<div id='popupWrapper'></div>");
var myID = $('.FloatingFrameLightBlue1').attr('id');
jQuery(myID).children().append("popupWrapper");
```

But it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the [`.append()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I did, since and new to `jQuery`, I tried `.append()` with  just one element and worked fine. when I tried to put it with the `children()` I started messing up. What solved it was using `appendTo()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you have a very simple example of it: http://jsfiddle.net/LhR79/

As they have already told you. You need to use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead of `append` and specify the selector type (class, id... ) using the `.` or the `#` preceding the name. In your case: `#popupWrapper` as popupWrapper is an ID and not a class.

Comment: just a note that this will only take child elements, not nodes. Text &/or important whitespace will not make it across: http://jsfiddle.net/s3dqj6r5/  here's a fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/51187961/2518317

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#" + myID).children().appendTo("#popupWrapper");
```

To select an element by its `id` you need to include `#` in the selector. So the line doing the appending needs to start with `jQuery("#" + myID)` rather than `jQuery(myID)`, and you need `"#popupWrapper"` not `"popupWrapper"`.

The other issue is that the [`.append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) works the opposite way around to what you want to do, that is, it inserts the content specified in the parameter to the end of each element in the set of matched elements. You want the [`.appendTo()` method](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Also, note that this line:

```
var myID = $('.FloatingFrameLightBlue1').attr('id');
```

...gets the id of the *first* element of that class (assuming there is at least one such element and that it has an id attribute, otherwise `myID` will be `undefined`).

But assuming there is only one element with that class you don't need the id to do the append, you can do this:

```
$('.FloatingFrameLightBlue1').children().appendTo("#popupWrapper");
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to use `appendTo()` instead of `append()` also give `#` with id

```
jQuery('#'+myID).children().appendTo("#popupWrapper");
```

Answer (score 4):

Example : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eRVfA/).

You're adding the string "popupWrapper" to the children, which doesn't make any sense.
You should do the following :

```
jQuery(myID).children().appendTo("#popupWrapper");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the other answers that if you have whitespace or text that needs to be moved you will need to use [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s3dqj6r5/3/)**

```js
$('#popupWrapper').append($('#' + myID)[0].childNodes);
```

---

[jQuery supports this actually](http://jsfiddle.net/s3dqj6r5/6/), you just need to use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead of `.children()`

```js
$('#' + myID).contents().appendTo('#popupWrapper');
```